# call a function from another file in c

Tags: c

I have two files `test-subseq.c` and `maxSeq.c`. In `test-subseq.c`, `test_maxSeq` calls `maxSeq`, so I need to add the prototype for `maxSeq` in `test-maxSeq.c` so that the compiler knows the function. In `maxSeq.c`, `maxSeq` calls `max`. My question is, in `test-maxSeq.c`, do I also need to add the prototype for `max`?

```
// maxSeq.c 

size_t max(size_t a, size_t b) {
  // returns the larger number between a and b
}

size_t maxSeq(int * array, size_t n) {
  /* 
   * returns the length of the maximum increasing contiguous subsequence
   * in the array and call max
   */
}
```

```
// test-subseq.c

size_t maxSeq(int * array, size_t n);

void test_maxSeq(int * array, size_t n, size_t expt) {
  size_t ans = maxSeq(array, n);
  assert(ans == expt)
}

int main(void) {
  int array0 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7};
  test_maxSeq(array0, 6, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typically in C, you put all function prototypes that you want to have global scope in a shared header file.  `size_t maxSeq(int * array, size_t n);` would go into that header file and you would `#include ""` the shared header in both C files.

Answer (score 2):

No, test-subseq.c only needs declarations for the functions which it will specifically call.

However, as the commenter said, it's better practice to put your declarations in a header file and `#include` that in test-subseq.c.

Answer (score 1):

Put maxSeq in a header file and then include the header file in test-subseq.c